# P&T Dropdown and "orderby" in Matrix

Tags: matrix, pt-dropdown

I need to display a matrix of schedule, which has the fields: `day`, `start_time`, `end_time`. The `day` field is P&T Dropdown with the following values: Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday.

Since I cannot control what order the user enters rows in the matrix, I'd like to display the schedule in "proper" order, starting with Sunday and ending with Saturday. How do I order the matrix rows by `day`? If I do something like: `orderby="day" sort="asc"`, it'll sort alphabetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try by having P&T Dropdown options (in the field setting) like:

```
0 : Sunday
1 : Monday
2 : Tuesday
3 : Wednesday
4 : Thursday
5 : Friday
6 : Saturday
```

To output day name, you should use `{custom_field_name:label}` which will output Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday.

If you are using `{custom_field_name}`, then it will output day number like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4...

Comment: It worked. Kindda. In CP, I see the drop down with Sunday, Monday, ..., as the drop down values. So, it's human readable. Then in my Safecracker form, I did `orderby="day" sort="asc"` and it seems to sort properly. The only problem is that it does not output the days. Instead it outputs the numbers. How do I display the day?

Comment: You should use: {custom_field_name:label} which output the day name instead of number value (day number).